# Centering Floating Divs or List Items in a Fluid Layout with Overflow

Tags: css, css-float, html-lists

I am creating a thumbnail gallery with floating list items that I would like centered in a fluid layout. I am able to do this without any issues when it is a single line but when it overflows they are no longer centered. Is this impossible purely with css? Here's an example:

```
<style>
#centeredmenu {
   float:left;
   width:100%;
   position:relative;
}
#centeredmenu ul {
   clear:left;
   float:left;
   list-style:none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   position:relative;
   left:50%;
   text-align:center;
}
#centeredmenu ul li {
   display:block;
   float:left;
   list-style:none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   position:relative;
   right:50%;
   width: 200px;
   background-color:black;
   border:1px solid white;
}
</style>
<div id="centeredmenu">
   <ul>
      <li>/</li>
      <li>/</li>
      <li>/</li>
      <li>/</li>
      <li>/</li>
      <li>/</li>
      <li>/</li>
      <li>/</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

If it can't be done purely with css can anyone point me in the direction to how it can be done with js?

Answer (score 1):

try this css, change the li from block to inline-block

```
#centeredmenu {

}
#centeredmenu ul {
   list-style:none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   text-align:center;
}
#centeredmenu ul li {
   display:inline-block;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   width: 200px;
   background-color:black;
   border:1px solid white;
}
```

Comment: This is so much more elegant than what I was trying to accomplish. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**RRcom Rest** y answer is good, but if you need this working with IE7, then *display: inline-block* will not work.

You can get the same effect for IE7 and modern browsers with this hack (see extra lines after "inline-block"):

```
#centeredmenu ul li {
   display:inline-block;
   *display: inline;
   *zoom: 1;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   width: 200px;
   background-color:black;
   border:1px solid white;
}
```

This hack will only be interpreted by IE7 (with the "*" hack), and only in this case will apply the display: inline and zoom: 1 rules. This forces inline element to has "layout". Thats is, inline elements that you can asign width or height properties (for example) but are in the same line.

[Here is the full doc explaining this hack](http://www.brunildo.org/test/InlineBlockLayout.html)